# CSS make banner look like it comes from the background

Tags: css

I'm trying to make it look like in the image.

[image]

This is what i have done so far:

[image]

But i cant figure out how to do the line so that it looks like the banner comes from behind the line.

My markup for the banner is this:

```
    <div class="step-arrows">
    <div class="top-line"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="top-line"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="top-line"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the styles i have done so far:

```
 .step-arrows {
   margin-left: 20%;
 }
.step-arrows .box {
   background-color: #2E8074;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
 }
.step-arrows .box > div {
   font-size: 80px;
 }

 .step-arrows .arrow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 50px solid #2E8074;
    border-left: 50.5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50.5px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -1px;
  }
```

I have tried to do it with box-shadow but i haven't been able to make it look very good :(

EDIT: (My last try)

```
.step-arrows .top-line {
    width: 150px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 67px 12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 67px 12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 9px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I have added my last try. It is not even close :(

Comment: First get rid of the top_line div, you will apply the shadow directly on the .box

Comment: i want it to point out at the sides. does that work with just shadow on the box?

Comment: This is a pretty difficult CSS task.  I can't dedicate more time to it right now unfortunately, but this is how far I got: https://jsfiddle.net/pn3qj6y4/.  You should probably use an image for that top line.

Comment: Something like this might be worth a bounty ;)

Comment: @JosephMarikle woow that looks great! Thanks a lot for you time.